# How to make multi-levels sticky-headers in React-Native?

Tags: react-native

**Like this**

[image]

I would prefer to use FlatList (or a VirtualizedList component).

Comment: This is exactly what you need (the same functionality as on your picture): https://docs-v2.nativebase.io/docs/examples/FlatListExample.html But, if you want to use SectionList instead of Flastslist you can try this tutorial: https://smali-kazmi.medium.com/react-native-sticky-date-like-whatsapp-using-inverted-sectionlist-c141f5933d55